# Opencart add name and email along with message in contact email

Tags: email, opencart, contacts

I'm getting only user's **message** via contact inquiry form.
I'm trying to add their name and email also in inquiry email. I'm not getting exact file to change.

Did anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **catalog/controller/information/contact.php**  find the line

```
$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

replace `$this->request->post['enquiry']` with `$msg_body`

just before this line add, the following line

```
$msg_body = "Sender's Name : ".$this->request->post['name']."  Sender's email : ".$this->request->post['email']. "  Enquiry :".$this->request->post['enquiry'];
```

Comment: you are awesome man. It worked liked charm... Can you tell me how to add one more custom field in this same custom form?

Comment: @Vin_fugen ask another question its a long answer and it may help future visitor too .

Comment: Thank for your kind words Chetan paliwali... I made it by myself. I just cloned existing fields in all theree files (language, controller and template)

Comment: Perfect @Chetan Paliwal, I just added some break lines:
$msg_body = "Sender's name: ".$this->request->post['name']."\n<br />Sender's E-mail : ".$this->request->post['email']. "\n<br />Message: ".$this->request->post['enquiry']; Thank you again.